# How can I significantly reduce casting time?

Tags: spells, optimization, adnd-2e

I've got some slow spells with casting times in the 1 hour to several day range, but only have 30 minutes to cast them due to impositions. By means of metamagic spells or magic items, or planar travel, is there a means by which I can reduce casting time drastically?

One of my goals is to fit a 360 minute spell into 30 minutes or less, if you need a specific example.

The spells in question are all above 5th level, if that matters.

Edit for relevance: Sha'ir have a 30 minute window to cast any spell their gen retrieves, regardless of its level.

> The sha’ir can cast the spell within three turns; thereafter the magic
>   is lost...The gen cannot set out to retrieve another spell for its
>   master until the previous magic has been cast or has expired.

Here's a small sample of the many spells this makes impossible:
*Find Familiar*, *Leomunds Secret Shelter*, *Magic Mirror*, *Awaken Intelligence*, *Create Major/Minor Helm*, *Move Earth*, *Antipathy*, *Create Atmosphere*, *Analyze Dweomer*, *Succor* and likely several other spells such as *identify* & *Enchant an Item*.

Comment: What's the actual situation, spells, and problem? It's possible that this casting time reduction plan isn't actually the best solution… and even if it is, details matter for answers avoiding non-useful methods (like things that need preparation that's not possible in that situation). Could you [edit] to more fully explain the problem?

Comment: the edit above demonstrates inherent problems with many traditional solutions such as chain contingency. I'm not sure how time magic might influence my 30 minute limit.

Comment: This is actually just really unclear and continues to be.

Answer (score 2):

With the limitation that the spells are of 6th level or higher, I can think of the following options.

Metamagic spells:

- Chain Contingency (ToM, p45) would allow you to pre-prepare up to 2 spells of 8th level or lower for instantaneous casting (you cast them in advance). You're limited to one Chain Contingency in effect at a time, and there's some other minor limitations.

Magic items:

- Any item that allows you to cast Timereaver (WSC IV, p941) at least once, such as a wand, scroll, etc. It's an 8th level common Chronomancer-only spell that can send you anytime from a second to several years into the past.
- If you're a priest, the Staff of Kitsyrral (WGA1 Falcon's Revenge, p59) could halve the casting time on up to 10 spell levels.
- I'm sure there's an item somewhere in the Encyclopedia Magica that does what you need (or close), but there's over 1500 pages to check, so that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Planar travel:

- If you could convince or otherwise compel a Noble or Royal Time Elemental (Dragon Magazine 69, p28-29), they can send you back in time an arbitrary amount. You would need to travel to the Plane of Time, since they cannot be summoned or conjured.

Comment: Aren't there planes where time travels a **lot** quicker, relative to the Prime Material, or which time can be spent on without time passing on the material?  I seem to recall Dungeonland being one of those, but also plenty of more common planes.

Comment: Astral and Ethereal have different time streams, but im not sure how that interacts with my "cast the spell within three turns; thereafter the magic is lost" restriction. Who's 3 turns? the Gen's, the plane i summon the spell on? or my own? variants of chronomancer magic *might* work, but im unsure.